# How to return nested comments using API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, api

Each **Car** has `has_many :comments` association

I have following method to return my cars:

```
 class Api::V1::CarsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def recent
      recent = Car.most_recent(params[:how_recent])
      comments = recent.each{|r| r.comments} ## ??
      respond_with(:recent => recent)
    end
  end
```

I get recent cars by:

```
curl -X GET http://cars.dev/api/v1/cars/recent -d "token=zzxWkB3SzDP3U1wDsJbY" -d "how_recent=20"
```

And I would like to get response like that:

```
"recent_with_comments":{"recent":[{"type":"ferrari","price":null,"user_id":78,"username":null,"comments":[{"id":1, "comment": "some text"},{"id":2, "comment": "some text 2"}]}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When rendering as json you can pass some additional params as shown http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/

basic example:

```
class Api::V1::CarsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def recent
    recent = Car.most_recent(params[:how_recent])
    comments = recent.each{|r| r.comments} ## ??
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render recent.as_json(:include => :comments) }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
comments = Comment.join(:car).merge(Car.most_recent(params[:how_recent]))
```

if u want custom json output use [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) gem

Comment: I agree. The rabl gem is great for anything more complex.