# Rails: How to obtain entire user object via json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, request

I want to retrieve an entire user object via a get request. Currently, on of my methods looks like this:

```
  def user
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    render :json => @user 
  end
```

This returns the following json:

```
"{\"annonymous_token\":null,\"email\":\"john1@doe.com\",\"name\":\"john1@doe.com\"}"
```

My user object / schema has a many-to-many relationship with another model called pictures.

```
  has_many :picturization
  has_many :pictures, :through => :picturization
```

How can I modify my code such that returning the user also returns the pictures the user has. If helpful, I am using devise for user authentication.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.as_json` and pass params as I show here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11336145/308701

so you could do:

```
def user
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  render :json => @user.as_json(:include => :pictures)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  `@user.to_json`?